# How to do segmentation based on some filters(e.g. TRAFFIC SIGNALS) from live streaming data

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am supposed to do traffic symbols recognition from live streaming data. Please tell me how to automate the process of segmentation. I am able to recognize the symbols using Neural Networks from segmented data but stuck in the segmentation part.
I have tried it using YOLO, but I think I am lacking something.
I have also tried it with openCV.
please help

[INPUT IMAGE FRAME FROM LIVE STREAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RMUu.png)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVn6z.png)

Comment: Are you looking for the segmented image to look like your OUTPUT image or do you want just the road sign with a black/blank background?

Comment: later one, just segment out the road sign

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow this link:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/tree/47c7af1cea5bbdedf1184963355e6418cb8b1b4f#how-to-train-pascal-voc-data

It's very simple to follow. You basicly need to do 2 steps. Installing and creating the data you want to use (road signs in your case).

So follow the installation guide and then try to find a dataset of road signs, use your own or create your own data set. You will need the annotation files as well (you can generate them yourself easily if you use your own dataset(s) - this is explained in the link as well). You don't need a huge amount of pictures, because darknet will augment the images automaticly (just resizing though). If you use a pretrained version you should get "ok" results pretty fast ~after 500 iterations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)